# Sketching direction field lines for second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Example.

$y''-y'-2y=0$

has the reduced 1st order system:

$y'=v$

$v'=2y+v$

this 1st order system has the general solution:

$y=C_1\begin{bmatrix}1/2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}e^{2t}+C_2\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$

How can I use the general solution above to draw a direction field and solution curves? I know how to do it for first order ODEs only and can't find anything for second order ODEs. Thanks.

Comment: You can draw the field lines in the $(y,v)$ plane, since you have all the equations solved, I think you can manage now.